# Procedurally place objects at runtime in Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime, procedural

I want my game to have stones, laying around on the terrain. The player can then pick up these stones. My terrain is pretty huge (around 5000x5000 in unity terms) though. I don't think it will be optimal to place hundreds (maby even thousands) of stones as game objects. As my game is multiplayer, I cannot just instantiate the stones as players walk because two players approaching each other would see stones spawning. I also cannot add the stones to the trees of my terrain and mass place them because it would conflict with my tree-chopping and cutting down script.

The solution to my mind would be to somehow procedurally place stones without players noticing. Is this the best way to do it? And if so, how?

I don't need any code but if someone could just outline how they would approach this please? I can't think of the best way to do this... Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Do you _have_ to generate the stones on the server?

Comment: No, as long as all players can see the same stones at the same positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stepped over this problem myself a short time ago. 
I would recommend to read about "Linear congruential generators" [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

They are used to generate pseudo-random numbers. But the random numbers depend on the given seed. So if every player has the same seed,  it should be possible to generate the stones while the players walk. Because of the same seed all the players would get the same random number at the position x,y and with this they would all generate the same stone at the same places.

Comment: I guess you would still get the "player A deduces the presence of player B due to stones appearing beyond player A's cut off distance" problem

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand you correctly. Did you mean that Player A would "see" player B because of the stones Player B generates? My idea was more to generate the stones only on the client. Therfore Player A would generate his stones and Player B would generate his stones, but neither of them would see each others stones.

Comment: and yet they would still get a stone in the same place. yes I think it would work. That's just how I interpreted the "I cannot just instantiate the stones as players walk..." bit

Comment: Perfect! So I can instantiate the stones on the client, meaning that no one will see each other's stones being generated - but their positions will be the same due to the seed. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: well of course if the stones should be more than just scenery (e.g. they can be collected) it must be possible to store this. If I remember correctly minecraft does it this way: It generates the world based on an LCG and only stores changes (destroyed or altered) blocks. The op could do this as well and store a list of collected stones and then the client could check if a possible stone should be instantiated depending on that list. But that is just a simple thought.

Comment: I guess this problem is really about optimization, so no solution is perfect